# Can I have an activity create another activity and wait for it to return information?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want the user to be able to click a button and move to a different activity to input some information and then press a button to "submit" that information to the previous screen.

Home Screen --button press--> Input Screen --"submit"--> Home Screen

Is there a way to start the input screen activity and have the home screen wait for a response?  This is the code I have now.

```
Intent inputIntent = new Intent(this, InputActivity.class);
try {
    // Attempt to start the activity
    startActivity(inputIntent);
    return true;
} catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Cannot find activity for intent: " + inputIntent.toString());
    return false;
}
```

I guess not only am I asking how to have the home screen "wait," but it would also be *ideal* to get back to the same home screen (not creating a NEW homescreen from the input screen).

Comment: startActivityForResult() will be better way, get a [example](http://rahulonblog.blogspot.in/2010/05/android-startactivityforresult-example.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Call `startActivityForResult()` to launch the second activity, and inside the second activity, call `finish()` to return to the first one. In the second activity, call `setResult()` to set the result which will be returned to the caller, and back in the first activity you retrieve the result in `onActivityResult()`. [This section](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) of the docs tells you more.

[This tutorial](http://www.mubasheralam.com/tutorials/android/how-start-new-activity-and-getting-results) takes you through the steps, and a quick search will throw up many similar tutorials.

Comment: I tried to use `startActivityForResult`, but apparently I was using it wrong. Very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The beauty is that your home `Activity` doesnT have to *wait*, but can react upon the activity result of your text editing Activity.

I m sure you have checked but I suggest you read the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and try to understand a little bit more.

A last headstart for you may be the [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)()

Good luck